# Creating a Mailing List (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a website where I have two text boxes for information entry. My "Submit" Button orders a PHP file to take the information in the two text boxes and copy/paste it into a text file named "Members.txt" The purpose is to take the information from the text boxes and create a mailing list. Now my problem is that I know the PHP file is calling for the text file because each time I hit submit, i can see on my ftp that the text file has been edited at the same time I try to submit to be apart of the list. In additon, the text file Is attempting to place the information into the text file as I can see that every time the "Submit" button is hit, the Text files entry lines are lower and lower. In otherwords a complete line is entered. but no text. And no, the text is not white. What am I doing wrong?

```
<h2>Join our Mailing List</h2>
   <form method="post" action="add.php" name="signup">
   <input type="hidden" name="pommo_signup" value="true" />
   <table border="0" bordercolor="#000000"
    bordercolordark="#000000" bordercolorlight="#000000">
     <tr>
       <td width="203" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> NAME:  <font size="4">
         <input name="name"
            type="text" size="20" maxlength="100" />
       </font></td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
       <td height="26" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> EMAIL: <font size="4">
         <input name="email"
            type="text" size="20" maxlength="100" />
         </font></td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
       <td height="31" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span style="text-align: left"></span><p align="middle">
         <input type="image" src="ok.jpg" />
       </p></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </form>

THEN BELOW IS THE FORM THAT IS SUPPOSED TO ADD TO THE TEXT BOX.

<?php
$filename = "members.txt";
$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd, filesize ($filename));
fclose ($fd);
if(strstr($contents,$email)) { 
print "You're already subscribed to this mailing list.";
}
else {
echo "Thank you $email for joining the mailing list";
if (!$save = fopen("members.txt","a")) {
exit;
}
fwrite($save,"$email\r\n");
fclose($save);
if (!$save = fopen("names.txt","a")) {
exit;
}
fwrite($save,"$name\r\n");
fclose($save);
mail("$email", "Fairview HiFi News Letter", "Welcome to the Fairview HiFi mailing list. Your exclusive source for product and promotional news and events.",
     "From: Newsletter@FairviewHiFi.com\r\n"
    ."Reply-To: NOREPLY@FairviewHiFi.com\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
}
?>
```

Comment: check out http://www.phplist.com/ for a ready to use mailing list application, as an alternative to rolling your own

Answer (score 4):

Use `$_POST['email']` not `$email`.

Your server has disabled register globals, which means that form inputs (and GET vars) aren't automatically avaliable in the form of `$formFieldName`, so you have to use $_POST/GET/COOKIE/...

And don't change this setting, it's a huge security hole if you enable register globals.

Answer (score 2):

Posted variables need to be referenced via `$_POST`. So your email will be:

```
print $_POST["email"];
```

And not merely `$email`. Additionally, since you're appending new lines, you might find a less-verbose solution to be appealing. See [`file_put_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with the `FILE_APPEND` flag:

```
<?php
  $file = 'people.txt';
  // The new person to add to the file
  $person = "John Smith\n";
  // Append the contents of $person to the file named by $file.
  file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```